# How to add talend jars dependency in maven project

Tags: java, maven, talend

We recently migrated from gradle to maven. We use more than 100 talend jars in our project. In gradle, there was no issue reading those jars, we just added those in lib folder. But maven project is not able to read these jars from lib folder even after adding them to class path. I can not add those many dependencies to pom.xml using system scope.

How can I add these jars to pom.xml, so that my project will be able to read them?

Do I need to use any maven plugin or any plugin provided by talend?

Answer (score 1):

In Maven, every direct dependency needs a `<dependency>` entry in the POM. No way around it.

The question is whether you need all those JARs in every project. Or these JARs have a dependency structure (POMs) themselves.

Generally, it is best to upload them to your Maven repository manager (Nexus/Artifactory/whatever) and then reference them in the POM as `<dependency>` entries.

Comment: The issue here is I can not add dependency for each jar in pom.xml since the jars are more than 100 in number. So I am looking for any plugin available to add talend jars to pom and then my project can read them. Please let me know if any such plugin can be used

Comment: You mean a plugin that generates 100+ dependency entries and puts them into the POM file? Why don't you just write a short script that does just that?

Comment: You choose some Maven coordinates like group id is something like com.talend, artifact id is file name and version is whatever appropriate. Then you write a script that iterates over the directory, installs the jars into the local repository and generates xml entries.